# Mono Method 'SqlParameter.set_TypeName' not found. & fastcgi

Tags: mono

Trying to run a site that is built under v4.5 profile.

I’m building with the latest docker image:

```
docker run --name=monobuild -it -v `pwd`/src:/var/src -v `pwd`/out/temp:/var/out -w /var/src/ -e MONO_IOMAP=case mono:latest xbuild /var/src/Api.Admin.sln /p:Configuration=Local /p:OutDir=/var/out/
```

I had this same error when compiling but I forgot how I got it to go away.

Now I’m getting it when attempting to run it in this docker image: https://github.com/seif/docker-mono-fastcgi-nginx

I suspect it’s not loading up the v4.5 libs but I have no clue of how to configure fastcgi to do this.

The error screen gives : Version Information: 4.0.4 (Stable 4.0.4.1/5ab4c0d Tue Aug 25 23:11:51 UTC 2015); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020

I’ve had a hell of a time trying to get this to run in apache/nginx. Any help would be super appreciated.

The Web.config has:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
```